# Publish PDF that is not able to download

Tags: security, pdf

Is it possible to publish a PDF somewhere, so that the user can only see it on that URL, so that the reader cannot download it?

Of course, it would stop the person from making screenshots, but more often than not people would assume the document is going to be there forever.

Comment: How is the user's computer supposed to display the contents of the PDF file if it can't download the PDF file?

Comment: The user only needs to **see** it on that URL. You can get that with server-side rendering of the PDF like I stated in my answer. The complete PDF is not downloaded. Only the content is transferred but not as PDF but as HTML.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the users to download the PDF you can't just give them a link/URL of the PDF. You need to render the PDF on the server side. It depends what kind of web-server you have on how you can do this.

You could use something like [this](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/). There are some demos [here](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/demo/).

For further examples you need to search for `server side pdf rendering` in combination with the kind of language you want. (PHP, ASP, etc...)

If you don't have your **own server** you can also use Google Drive (for free). You can share your PDF's (with a private link) and check the setting that users can't download the PDF. The PDF will be rendered by Google on screen only and users can't download the PDF.

[image]